MVVM - model to data conversion - service layer vs view model
In our Winui3 application, we are following MVVM architecture. I have InvoiceData, InvoiceModel, InvoiceViewModel and InvoiceService for my Invoice module.
When saving an Invoice from the view model, I need to convert the InvoiceModel to InvoiceData to hit the API. Converting the model to data depends on a few other properties in the view model.
Let us say if the IsXFeatureEnabled/IsXFeatureVisible property in the view model is true, then I need to copy 5 properties in the model to data, else I will ignore them. I cannot have those feature properties in the model as it is meta and needed for UI visibility.
In the above case, can I have the model to data conversion in the view model layer itself, so that I can access all the needed properties directly and pass the resultant data object to the InvoiceService, which will take care of the further API handling.
The reason for this query is that the MVVM sample project by Microsoft has those conversion methods in the service layer (https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample). Is moving those methods to view model against the architecture rules?

The InvoiceModel has to contain any information needed. Your "it is only meta for UI" will affect the logic so it is more than just meta

@SirRufo In my InvoiceViewModel, I have Models like InvoiceModel, List etc. Lets say IsXFeatureEnabled is needed for both the InvoiceModel and LineItemModel, Do I need to have those properties in all the Model objects inside the list? Also as I have studied, the properties related to the UI should be placed in ViewModel.

But your problem is the conversion from Model to Data. The Model should contain everything you need to update/create the Data. If there is one missing then add it. But there are more options depending on the context - we do not know why you ignore the properties and what is the impact on the data so we can only judge as general as you ask

Can you post a sample code of how your ViewModel, Model and Data? And how you are trying to convert the Model to Data?

It doesn't matter from my view. Whether the conversion is in view model or service layer is out of the MVVM architecture.
